# How to utilize Android BLE bonding feature using RxAndroidBLE Library?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I didn't find anything about that in RxAndroidBLE sample code/description.
In vanilla Android BLE API I can easily use BluetoothDevice.createBond() method for that, but i am totally confused how to do the same using RxAndroidBLE.

Comment: Have you some code example, of what you tried?

Comment: In simple words, I am tried to make my BLE connection encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

`RxAndroidBle` does not support bonding / encryption as for the version `1.1.0`. You can create the bond using standard Android BLE API though.

<del>You will have a problem on subsequent connections when you will try to read / write encrypted characteristics as the Android BLE API is establishing encryption on an actual read / write of the characteristic and returns an error on first attempt — that error is effectively closing the connection within the library.</del>

Edit: Since version `1.3.0` errors on individual operations are no longer closing the connection which gives an opportunity to retry them after the encryption is established.

Comment: Do you have a plan to support bonding / encryption in further versions?

Comment: Yes — we do have a plan to support bonding / encryption — but it is not on the top of our priority list unfortunately. This is an open source project so anyone who would like to help us and contribute is welcome.

Comment: The library was updated to version `1.3.0` and it should be possible to use encrypted characteristics now.

Comment: Great news! Will try it asap